# Button goes outside of div when I shrink the browser

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page created using html and css, when I shrink the browser the button `small-button` goes outside of the div and I don't know why, I want to keep it in the div no matter how much I shrink the browser so that it is responsive. How can I do that?

here is my code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;    
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.header {
  height: 8%;
}


.nav-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 27px;

  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI',sans-serif;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.a-container {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 27px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  height: 288px;
  width: 100%;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8%;

  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #000000;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo-section {
  margin-top: 1.3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.logo-img {
  padding: 6px;
}

.first-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/first-image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.first-section-p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 314px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: #262262;
}

.small-button {
  width: 331px;
  height: 92px;

  margin-left: 12%;
  background-color: #e7af17;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.second-section-text {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 0.7;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  margin-left: 12%;
}



@media (min-width: 1281px) {

  .first-section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      background-image: url("/assets/images/first-image.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
  }

  .small-button {
      width: 331px;
      height: 92px;

      margin-top: 8%;
      margin-left: 12%;
      background-color: #e7af17;
      font-family: SegoeUI;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 900;
      color: white;
      border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="headers">
        <div class="nav">
            <h1 class="nav-h1">Logo</h1>
            <div class="a-container">
                <a>About</a>
                <a>Vision</a>
                <a>Solutions</a>
                <a>Technology</a>
                <a>Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-section">
                <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
                <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inside">
            <div class="first-section">
                <p class="first-section-p">Turnkey platforms <br> for businesses looking to rule the online market
                </p>
                <button class="small-button">LEARN MORE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="second-section">
                <p class="second-section-text">WHAT</p>
                <p class="second-section-text">WHE DO</p>
                <p class="second-section-text">BEST</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

make you sure that you have this meta in html file `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` and trying to change the sizes and position of the elements that you want to resize but don't define all properties
just define the properties that want to change

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.header {
  height: 8%;
}

.nav-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 27px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.a-container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  height: 288px;
  width: 100%;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8%;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #000000;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo-section {
  margin-top: 1.3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.logo-img {
  padding: 6px;
}

.first-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/first-image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.first-section-p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 314px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: #262262;
}

.small-button {
  width: 331px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-left: 12%;
  background-color: #e7af17;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.second-section-text {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 0.7;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .first-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/first-image.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .small-button {
    width: 321px;
    height: 82px;
    margin-top: -28%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    background-color: #e7af17;
    font-family: SegoeUI;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .small-button {
    margin-top: -30%;
    margin-left: 14%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1 class="nav-h1">Logo</h1>
      <div class="a-container">
        <a>About</a>
        <a>Vision</a>
        <a>Solutions</a>
        <a>Technology</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="logo-section">
        <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
        <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside">
      <div class="first-section">
        <p class="first-section-p">Turnkey platforms <br> for businesses looking to rule the online market
        </p>
        <button class="small-button">LEARN MORE</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-section">
        <p class="second-section-text">WHAT</p>
        <p class="second-section-text">WHE DO</p>
        <p class="second-section-text">BEST</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the viewport with a `meta` tag.

See this resource: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: I have the ```meta``` tag already and it doesn't help

Comment: Might be a silly thing to check, but make sure you set the viewport (with the `meta` tag) on the same page the button is on

Comment: yep I checked, it's on the same page

Comment: These css classes might help: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the @media css rule:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 'your device width') {
    .element{
        //styling rules here
    }
}
```

You can use this rule more than one time to make your website responsive for more device widths.